# How to make an Android view containing an embedded RecyclerView to scroll as a single piece?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have this piece of layout or Android which is problematic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/influencerMainPhotoImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/photos_list"
    android:name="com.company.android.InfluencerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.company.android.InfluencerFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_photo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the embedded RecyclerView is doing nested scrolling (ie. it scrolls within itself) - I don't want this.

**I'd like to the entire screen to scroll as a single piece.**

I tried to set "view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);" (on the LinearLayout view) but it says it works only for API 21 and above. My project is set to min API 15.

*What can I do to make the entire screen scroll as a single piece?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `View` with `ViewCompat`(v4 compat lib):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html

where you have the `setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean);` method.